# Oracle 12C + Java + XMLType

Tags: java, xml, oracle

Olá, 
Bom dia na minha empresa estamos testando o Oracle 12c. E eu encontrei um "probleminha" para fazer consulta de um campo que é o tipo XMLType. 
Nós guardamos todos os xml de nfe no banco, então sempre temos que consultar esse xml. 
O problema é o seguinte, quando eu faço a consulta no Oracle 12, o xml vem formatado, e assim perde a assinatura digital do arquivo. 
Alguém tem alguma dica de como trazer esse xml não formatado?!? 
qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda. 
Segue meu código:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select  nfe_xml from nfe_xml where NFE_CHAVE_ACESSO = ?");

st.setString(1, chaveAcesso);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
OracleResultSet orset = (OracleResultSet) rs;
while(orset.next())
{ 
    //orset.getOPAQUE(1);
    //XMLType poxml = XMLType.createXML(orset.getOPAQUE("NFE_XML"));
    XMLType poxml = (XMLType)orset.getObject(1); 

    String sXml = ( poxml).getStringVal();
    System.out.println("xml: "+sXml);

    podoc = (Document)poxml.getDOM();
    Util.gravarXmlNfe("C:\\NFE\\"+chaveAcesso+".xml", podoc);
    String sXml2 =Util.convert(podoc, null) ;
    System.out.println(sXml2);
}
```

Comment: Você está usando alguma *feature* específica de manipulação XML no banco? Se não um caminho possível é substituir o seu tipo por um `CLOB`.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar o método `getStringVal` para obter o conteúdo do XML, você pode usar o método que `getInputStream` que retorna um `InputStream` para você ler o XML byte a byte do banco de dados.

Certifique-se que o XML está sendo gravado no banco de dados em uma coluna do tipo `LOB`, pois só assim a informação original será preservada. Isso é explicado [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB5125).